# eliminar valores repetidos array java

Tags: java

Estou a tentar imprimir um Array sem repetições, ou seja tenho:

```
ja={1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,8,9};
```

e o resultado será:

```
jaresul={1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9}
```

ideias?

Comment: O qualidade da pergunta está baixa, tente ser mais específico e colocar um pouco sobre as suas tentativas de resolver o problema ou pesquisar locais onde a pergunta pode ter sido respondida. Para as próximas perguntas recomendo a leitura de **[Como Fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue uma implementação direta, sem uso da API Collections, que resulta num vetor sem repetidos:

```js
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestIntArray {

    public static void main( String[ ] args ) {
        int[ ] original = { 1 , 3 , 5 , 7 , 9 , 5 , 3 };

        // remover repetidos
        int[ ] unicos = new int[ original.length ];
        int qtd = 0;
        for( int i = 0 ; i < original.length ; i++ ) {
            boolean existe = false;
            for( int j = 0 ; j < qtd ; j++ ) {
                if( unicos[ j ] == original[ i ] ) {
                    existe = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if( !existe ) {
                unicos[ qtd++ ] = original[ i ];
            }
        }

        // ajuste do tamanho do vetor resultante
        unicos = Arrays.copyOf( unicos , qtd );

        // imprime resultado
        for( int i = 0 ; i < unicos.length ; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( "" + i + " = " + unicos[ i ] );
        }

    }
}
```

Pode adaptar isso num método que recebe um `int[]` e retorna um `int[]`.

Comment: Brilhante muito agradecido.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode adicionar todos em um Set e então imprimir o objeto:

```
int[] ja={1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,8,9};
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for(int a: ja) {
    set.add(a);
}
System.out.println(set);
```

O código acima imprime:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]

O Set é uma coleção de objetos únicos, portanto, quando se adiciona elementos repetidos nele esses elementos são automaticamente descartados.

#### Alternativa

Uma alternativa para deixar seu código mais simples é usar um vetor de `Integer` ao invés de um vetor de `int`, pois assim é possível adicionar todos os elementos do vetor ao sua variável `set` com apenas um comando, seu código ficaria assim:

```
Integer[] ja={1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,8,9};
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(ja));
System.out.println(set);
```

O resultado é o mesmo.

A diferença é que no primeiro código o compilador faz um Autoboxing do seu valor primitivo para objeto da sua variável `set` ao usar o método `add()`, entretanto não é possível usar o método `Arrays.asList()` com um vetor de `int` pois ele converte seu vetor em um `List<int[]>`, pois o `int[]` é considerado um objeto, e também pois não há Autoboxing de `int[]` para `Integer[]`.

#### Retornando para vetor

Para retornar o valor de `set` para vetor basta fazer:

```
Integer[] jb = set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]);
```

Se precisa transformar para vetor de `int` terá que ser algo mais manual, como:

```
int cont = 0;
int[] jaresul = new int[ja.length];
for (Integer i : jb) {
    jaresul[cont++] = i;
}
```

Seu `jaresul` conterá os elementos do `jaresul` sem duplicados.

Referências: [Set (Java Platform SE7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html); [Arrays.asList (Java Platform SE7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Comment: tem que retornar int[], dai a tua solução não me parece que se aplique.

Comment: @board11 veja se agora atende

Comment: entendo a tua solução o que acontece é tenho que fazer obrigatoriamente return do resultado, ora se com a tua solução faço return jb era dar erro por não consegue converter de integer[] para int[]

Comment: @board11 viu minha ultima edição? só converti de volta de set para Integer[] e então para int[], acredito que é isso que pediu, ou estou enganado?

Answer (score 1):

Com Java8:

```
Integer[] ja = {1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,8,9};
List<Integer> distinctList = Arrays.asList(ja).stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

***Com While para pesquisar e For para imprimir ...***

```
        int[] ja = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9,9,7};
        Arrays.sort(ja);
        int[] jj = new int[ja.length];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;     
        int x = 0;
        boolean find;
        while (i < ja.length) { 
            if (i == 0){
                jj[j] = ja[i];
                j++;
            } else {
                x = 0;
                find = false;
                while (x < j && find == false){
                    if (jj[x] == ja[i]) { find = true; }                    
                    x++;
                }
                if (find == false){
                    jj[j] = ja[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }            
        ja = Arrays.copyOf(jj, j);            
        for(int r : ja){
            System.out.println(r);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es tu solucion.

saludos desde México.

```
int[] ja = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9};
int[] res = Arrays.stream(ja).distinct().toArray();
for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(res[i]);
}
```