# Verificar caracter e valor repetido em array de strings

Tags: java

Tenho um Array de strings

```
 String[] jt = { "João Mendonça", "Mário Andrade", "João Mendonça"});
```

O que é suposto é que se **verifique** se o array contém **no mínimo um caracter letra** e que **não tenha nenhum nome repetido**, ou seja, neste caso especifico contém no min uma letra e têm um nome repetido. o output esperado será:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: nome repetido
```

o meu problema está em como fazer a verificação de se tem no mínimo um caracter letra e como verificar se tem nome repetido.

**Explicando melhor:**

Tenho Array de String JT ao qual quero fazer 2 verificações:

1- verificar se no minimo existe 1 caracter que seja letra.

2 - Verificar se existem nomes igual:   `jt= {"nome","nome","nome")`, caso existe retorna

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: nome repetido
```

Comment: voce poderia implementar o código de [eliminar valores repetidos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14339/3117) mudando de int para String né?

Comment: está a falar sobre a repetição, foi o que imaginei mas não funciona mesmo trocando os ints para strings

Comment: pq não funciona? oq deu de errado?

Comment: @board11 Têm um nome repetido onde?

Comment: erro meu, já editei

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro podes fazer uma comparação de cada string e verificar se existe mais algum registo com esse valor [teu exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14429/7210). Ou podes fazer de outra forma que me lembrei agora:

```
List jtLista = Arrays.asList(jt); //Lista com todos os elementos
Set jtSet = new HashSet(jtList);  //Lista sem elementos repetidos
if(jtSet.size()< jtList.size())
    //tem repetidos
```

Depois para verificar se tem pelo menos um caracter podes fazer assim:

```
//compila a expressão regular com o alfabeto em maiúsculas e minúsculas
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");  
// faz o match da string "AB 45"  com a expressão regular.
Matcher m = p.matcher("AB 45");         

//se existirem resultados é porque houve match, ou seja, contém letras.
if(m.find())  
  System.out.println("A string contem letras");
```

Comment: Desculpa, nao estou a entender bem, consegues explicar melhor o teu código?

Comment: Só novo por cá. porque ficou quebrado?

Comment: @Math a outra resposta era daqui mesmo e foi apagada. Vou retirar o link.

Comment: estava a pensar mais em algo do tipo:
for (int k=0; k< autores.length; k++){
  if (autores[k].contains("[a-z]")){
   // getAutores();
   System.out.print("contem letras");
  }
  }

lógico que não funciona

Comment: @board11 já completei a resposta. Tem uma forma mais fácil de ver se tem repetidos. Não sei qual a melhor forma, mas fica a ideia.

Answer (score 0):

A parte do repetido resolvi assim(com a ajuda de um user que postou aqui):

```
int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    boolean find = false;
    while (i < autores.length && find == false) {
        j++;
        while (j < autores.length && find == false) {
            find = autores[i].equals(autores[j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (find == true) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Existem autores repetidos"); 
    } else {
        getAutores();

    }
```